# SQL Server : group by yesterday's 9am to today's 9pm

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, group-by

```
50  2016-07-29 04:40:44.000
70  2016-07-29 04:40:33.000
30  2016-07-29 03:50:56.000
15  2016-07-28 00:03:16.000
74  2016-07-28 23:38:18.000
15  2016-07-28 23:30:11.000
7   2016-07-28 23:22:37.000
10  2016-07-28 21:02:19.000
```

How can I achieve to group yesterday and today?

I must see only one row:

```
271  2016-07-28
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular data, you can just do:

```
select sum(col1), cast(max(col2) as date)
from t;
```

You might want a `where` clause:

```
where col2 >= dateadd(hour, -15, cast(getdate() as date)) and
      col2 < dateadd(hour, 21, (cast getdate() as date))
```